# How to calculate the CDF for a flipped distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, linear-transformations

Let'say I have a random variable $X$ that has a certain PDF $f(x)$ and CDF $F(x)$. If I have a variable $Y$ that is defined as $Y=100-X$, then how can I find the PDF and CDF of $Y$? Will the PDF just be $f(100-X)$ and the CDF will be the integral of that? I am having some trouble figuring this out because when I do it this way, the CDF becomes negative since the function is flipped. Any help regarding the process and intuition of figuring this out would be very helpful. For example, if $X$ has an exponential distribution how would this work?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a general linear change of variables $Y = aX + b$. A routine method is to transform with the CDFs (suppose that $ a> 0$)
$$ F_Y(y) = P(Y \le y) = P(aX + b \le y) = P(X \le (y - b)/a) = F_X((y-b)/a). $$
Differentiation yields:
$$ f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{a}f_X \left(\frac{y-b}{a} \right). $$
Try to do the same calculation when $ a < 0$ and check what comes out with the exponential distribution.

Comment: Thank you! Here is what I have:  

$F(x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda*x}$
$F_Y(y) = P(b-X≤y) = P(-X≤y-b) = P(X>b-y) = 1 -  P(X≤b-y)) = 1-F_X(b-y)$  
Differentiation leads to:  
$f_y(y) = f_Y(y) = f_X(b-y)$   where
$f_X(x) = \lambda * e^{-\lambda*x}$
Would this be correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me, you should also be careful about the new domain (e.g. $y$ is not just positive.)

Comment: How would the new domain be calculated? The original domain is $x>=0$ so would the domain for y become $y>=b$?

Comment: No. You can check this. Try integrating $\int_b^\infty f_Y(y) \ dy$. Does this equal 1? Instead, note that $x > 0$ implies that $100 - y > 0$ and so $100 > y$.

Comment: I understand. I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

$F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y)$

$= \mathbb{P}(100-X \leq y)$

$= \mathbb{P}(X \geq 100-y) $

$= 1 - \mathbb{P}(X<100-y) $

$= 1 - F_X(100-y)$ (assuming continuity)

Since $F_x(\cdot) \in [0,1]$, so is $F_Y$.

You can differentiate the above to get $f_Y(y) = f_X(100-y)$.